# Filter out a specific word in Excel Vba

Tags: string, excel, vba, filter

I want to filter out specific words and from a string.
For example, 
"This is a sample file."
word to be filtered out in excel vba = "file".
Please help, In dire need of this code. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Instr("This is a sample file.", "file")` will give you the position of the first occurrence of "file" in the longer string, or 0 if it not there.

You can remove elements of a string using `Left`, `Mid` and `Right`. `Len` gives you the length of a string.

Putting all this together:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim s1 As String
    Dim s2 As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    s1 = "This is a sample file."
    s2 = "file"
    pos = InStr(s1, s2)
    If pos > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Left(s1, pos - 1) & Mid(s1, pos + Len(s2))
    End If
End Sub
```